# How to replicate C++ rand in another language's random function?

Tags: c++, math, random, modulus

I am using an internal language in my company and they only have `Random()` that returns a float between 0 and 1.

I need to port a piece of C++ code that use `rand()`:

```
int b = rand() % (i+1);
```

I looked at the docs, but not sure how I can use my `Random()` to generate a number between 0 and `i+1` which is what the above code does, right?

I tried multiplying `i+1` with `Random()` but didn't get the same results, that's why I am not sure if what I am doing is correct.

I expect difference between the results due to different random functions, but still I want to be sure I am translating it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to multiply `Random()` with `i` and not `i+1`.

C++ `rand()` returns an integer between `0` and `RAND_MAX` but your `Random()` returns a float between `0` and `1`, so multiplying the output of `Random()` with `i` and taking the integer portion of the result will give you an integer in `[0,i]` which is what `rand() %(i+1)` gives.

Comment: Thanks I don't understand why the original code uses `i+1` though? It loops backwards starting with the last index, so wouldn't i+1 give an index larger than the max index which is (num_items - 1)?

Comment: `(a +ve int) % N` returns a number between `0` and `N-1` (both inclusive).

Comment: If the original said rand() % (i + 1) then you definitely want to replace it with Random()*(i + 1). I'm willing to be that Random() produces a number in the range [0, 1) , so multiplying by i produces the range [0, i) and truncating to int will result in [0, i-1].

Comment: @rici, If you're unsure whether `Random()` could return 1.0 or not you can multiply by `i+0.999999999999999` instead of `i+1`.

Answer (score 2):

Rand() give you a number between 0 and RAND_MAX, which after applying the mod operator you end up with a number between 0 and i (including i).

To do the same with Random() you'll need to multiply by ( i+1 ), then take the floor of that (round down):

```
b = floor( Random() * (i+1) )
```

This will give you a number from 0 to i (including the fence posts) as required.